# Role(s) of 也 inside 我猜了三次，也没猜对。

Tags: grammar

> 我猜了三次，也没猜对。

My translation : *I guessed 3 times and still being unable to guess correctly.*

Seems applying "also" for 也 doesn't work here.

Nextly I thought applying [连 什么 都/也 structure](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22even%22_with_%22lian%22_and_%22dou%22) may work in the original Chinese sentence.

So the original sentence might be converted into

> **连**我猜了三次，也**我还没**猜对。

My translation : *Even I guessed 3 times, still I've being unable to guess the correct one.*

Is this my analysis correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Seems applying "also" for 也 doesn't work here

也 here means "all",  in response to 三次 (three times, not the third time)

三次[**也**] = [**all**] three times

我猜了三次，也没猜对。 = 我三次也没猜对 (I guessed wrong all three times)

**Example for 也 means "also":**

第一次猜错了 Guessed wrong the first time

第二次[又]猜错了 Guessed wrong [again] the second time

第三次[也]猜错了 Guessed wrong [also] the third time

**Example for 也 means "all":**

三次[也/都]猜错了 = Guessed wrong [all] three times

Comment: Can the comma at 我猜了三次，也没猜对 be moved to immediately after 次 without losing the logic or naturality? namely 我猜了三次也，没猜对

Comment: You can write: "我也猜了三次，没猜对" but "我猜了三次也，没猜对 " is totally wrong

Comment: “我也猜了三次，没猜对”和”我猜了三次，也没猜对“不是一个意思。

Comment: 我猜了三次，也没猜对。 = 我猜了三次也没猜对。 = 我猜了三次，全没猜对。 = 我猜了三次，全猜错了。

Answer (score 1):

我猜了三次，也(either)没(not)猜对。I guessed three times, and **neither** was correct.

To be correct, your sentence should be modified to:

- 连猜了三次，我也还没猜对。or 我连猜了三次，也还没猜对。- I made three consecutive guesses, yet **neither** was correct.

Answer (score 1):

In Chinese, the word "**也**" has a primary meaning of "**the same as the other one**", but in practice, its usage is extensive and has a lot of extended meanings. A sentence with "**也**" becomes very tricky because the "**other one**", the object being used as the baseline, is usually not directly given but implied in the context.

For example, the mom said to her son "你就是得60分**也**行啊，结果你只考了45分。" = "It could be still OK if you got 60, but in fact you got only 45." The question is what the standard in the mother's mind is. I guess the mom wants to tell that "我希望你能得到80分。你就是得60分**也**行啊，结果你只考了45分。".

In your question, "我猜了三次，**也**没猜对。" that implies the situation "我猜了三次，第一次和第二次没有猜对，第三次**也**没猜对。" It is about the same as saying "**都**没猜对。" I guess the speaker wants to tell us that, after being wrong twice, he hoped that he could be right in the third trial. But it turned out that the last result was the **same as** the previous ones.